# Amazon Ec2 instance access using elastic ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image]

I installed jboss in my ec2 instance. My elastic ip address 52.16.53.218.

I deployed my retailproduct application. Server is started. Deployed successfully, but I can't access my application.

I tried below ways:

> http://localhost:8080/retailcare
>
> http://127.0.0.1:8080/retailcare
>
> http://52.16.53.218:8080/retailcare

I can't access. Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you curl it locally? are the security groups set up?

Comment: yes security group setup available

Comment: Please show a screenshot of your security group config, or describe it with text.

Comment: I updated  Security Group: in my question itself

Comment: Is your instance inside a VPC?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing `localhost` stays totally within the Amazon EC2 instance, so it would not be impacted by Security Group.

If you are able to SSH/RDP to the actual server and accessing `http://localhost:8080/retailcare` does not work, then it is a problem with your application or JBoss configuration.

Comment: no one knows answer means, don't give downvoted stuff like that . above question is very important for me .ok.